# Problem in accessing URLs of mean app on azure server

Tags: angular, mongodb, azure, mean-stack

I am new learner in mean Stack and don't know how to access URLs after hosting on azure specially angular links .I am trying to deploy by the the help  of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DeV01p73_8 .I want to know the right way

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the video as is, I assume you would have deployed your application to an Azure VM as well. As shown in the video, the created VM is assigned a Public address 13.xx.251.xx.

Hence you should be able to access your app via the same Public IP address after opening port 80 on the VM. The same tutorial can also be accessed via this detailed [MS Learn module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-a-web-app-with-mean-on-a-linux-vm/).

Here is another resource that walks you through [deploying a MEAN App to Azure Web Apps on Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/deploy-a-mean-app-to-azure/) instead.